# Soundcloud API - Upload image from external URL for track artwork, using SC.recordupload

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

How can I upload track artwork using the SC.recordUpload function, when the location of the image is an external URL?

My erroneous code:

```
imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.4993603,-0.1074693&zoom=12&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false";

....(connection code and track recording)....

SC.recordUpload({
    track: {
        title: "New track",
        description: "Track description",
        sharing: "public",
        artwork_data: imageObj
      }
    }, function(track){
        //Track uploaded!
        $("#uploadStatus").html("Track uploaded!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the SoundCloud JS SDK unfortunately does not support artwork uploading.

Sorry about that.